# Databricks to S3 - The backend could not get session tokens for path

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, linked-server

I'm trying to move data from the dbfs databricks to my S3 bucket, however, I'm stuck in this error: The backend could not get session tokens for path /mnt/s3/mybucket-upload/product.csv.gz. Did you remove the AWS key for the mount point?

```
Moving dbfs:/tmp/databricks2s3/product/part-00000-tid-7154689887306924257-8bd689b8-fc4d-46a1-b207-8a6b51aade55-411806-1-c000.csv.gz to /mnt/s3/mybucket-upload/product.csv.gz
An error occurred while calling z:com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils.mv.
: com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.common.InvalidMountException: 
The backend could not get session tokens for path /mnt/s3/mybucket-upload/product.csv.gz. Did you remove the AWS key for the mount point?
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.common.InvalidMountException$.apply(DataMessages.scala:520)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.filesystem.MountEntryResolver.resolve(MountEntryResolver.scala:61)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DBFSV2.resolve(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$getFileStatus$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:757)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$getFileStatus$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:756)
    at com.databricks.s3a.S3AExeceptionUtils$.convertAWSExceptionToJavaIOException(DatabricksStreamUtils.scala:119)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$getFileStatus$1.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:756)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$getFileStatus$1.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:756)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$recordOperation$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:440)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:251)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:246)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withAttributionContext(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:450)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:288)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withAttributionTags(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:450)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:421)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.recordOperation(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:450)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.getFileStatus(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:755)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystem.getFileStatus(DatabricksFileSystem.scala:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkDest(FileUtil.java:496)
```

And here's how I set up the bucket:

```
  try:
    dbutils.fs.mount(
      f's3n://{s3_accesskey_id}:{parse.quote(s3_secret_access_key, "")}@mybucket-upload/mylink', 
     '/mnt/s3/mybucket-upload/mylink')
  except Exception as error:
    if ('Directory already mounted' not in str(error)):
      raise error
```

I tried to pass AWS credentials directly into the code, but it also doesn't work.

Interestingly, everything works perfectly in DEV

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I saved the data to the blob and then moved it to s3 using "boto3"